# Date timezone getting changed when using spring boot default jackson mapping

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

I have spring boot rest service which call another service xyz and receive date in format yyyy-MM-ddXXX from json. But time Zone of of date is getting changed in my service response. Suppose I am getting date in JSON from service xyz as "date": "2018-08-27-07:00" but my service response is returning   date : "2018-08-27-04:00". Offset getting changed. Date field in my POJO is . I want to use the same offset I am getting from backend service and it can be any offset.

```
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-ddXXX")
   private Calendar date;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Calendar` (and `Date`) use implicit time conversions to adjust it to your time zone. And almost always it is something that not expected.

To avoid this use `java.time` classes (such as `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`, or even `LocalDateTime` if you do not need to work wit time zones).

And small offtopic advice: try to use time format aligned to `ISO8601` standard (like `2018-08-24T22:30:00`)

Comment: problem is i can not change Calendar type as it is legacy code. I have to use that code .